# Как сохранять полученый поток stream в файл?

Tags: c#

Получил поток stream, теперь как его можно сохранить на диск?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможный вариант - использовать класс [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.aspx):

```
public void SaveStreamToFile(string filename, Stream stream)
{
    if (stream.Length != 0)
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filename, (int)stream.Length))
        {
            // Размещает массив общим размером равным размеру потока
            // Могут быть трудности с выделением памяти для больших объемов
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];

            stream.Read(data, 0, (int)data.Length);
            fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
         }    
}
```

Comment: Проблема решена! Мой метод тоже был правильный просто почему то stream.length был = null и соответственно никак не мог сохранить . Позже я исправил эту ошибку.

Comment: Лучше заюзать (в `.NET4+`) или посмотреть, как реализован `extension` метод [`CopyTo`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx)